# Second If statement is not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

My son wrote a code, it's quite simple but second if statement isn't working as expected.

```
print ('hi')
print ('How are you?')
print ('Hope ok!')
print ('So I will ask you a few questions')
print ('What is 2 + 2?')
answer = input() 
if answer == 4:
    print ('Well done!')
else:
    print ('Are you able to count?')
    print ('Well anyway.Another question.')
    print ('What is 50 % 50?')

anser = input() 

if anser == 1:
    print ('Well done!')
elif anser == 5:
    print ('What?')
elif anser == 50:
    print ('Who are you? Are you already in 1st class?')
else:
    print ('Ok.I got you.You cannot count.')
    print ('Арролбьітрцо')
    print ('The code is broken! can you fix it?')
    print ('Press Enter')
    input()
    for i in range (1,70):
        print ('Error')
```

It doesn't matter what second answer is, program still prints

"Ok.I got you.You cannot count.
Арролбьітрцо
The code is broken! can you fix it?
Press Enter"

even if you type 1 or 5...

Can anyone suggest please what is wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: The return value of `input()` (in Python 3.x, at least) is always a string.  Strings are never equal to any integer...

Comment: As an aside, I appreciate how aggressive the responses to a wrong answer are x)

Comment: @HFBrowning people are starving for good questions & answers tonight...

Comment: @HF Especially when the "right" answer to 50 % 50 is considered to be 1.

Answer (score 1):

the reason is because `anser` is a str. if you put `print(type(anser))` after `anser = input()` you will see

> `<class 'str'>`

change `if anser == 1:` to  `if anser == '1':` then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Using input() will always result in a string unless you specify otherwise.

To make it an integer use:

```
answer = int(input("question"))
```

An alternative would be:

```
if int(answer) == 1:
```

This will make it an integer so you are comparing two numbers in the if statement

Comment: that's only in python 3.

Comment: Good point, I will edit the question. It is clear the OP is using python3 because of the brackets on print()

Comment: brackets on print also work on python 2 :)

Comment: Do they? Well seems I've learnt something too ;)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the question is tagged with python 3 and if this isn't python 3 then it's not clear why the program wouldn't work.

Comment: @AlexHall you're right. But OP could have copied some code from correct python 2 program. Anyway, I've pulled the plug on that one. Asked soooo many times...

Comment: @OlegV If this answers your question don't forget to click on the tick to the left of my question to mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Essentially, when you compare using the == operator using one of more objects, Python will check if the pointers are the same (essentially, if they're in the same location in the memory). You have two types of data, primitives (like ints or booleans) and objects. Strings don't compare with pimitives when using the == operator, so you have to convert the numbers to strings or convert the input to an int

Rather than: if anser == 5:

Do: if int(anser) == 5:

Or: if anser == '5'

Comment: You're thinking of Java. The conversion is necessary but there is no `.equals` in Python - `==` is the equivalent. Java's `==` is like Python's `is`.

Comment: Alex - You're right. I had a bit of a brain fart but edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: No, saying "Python will check if the pointers are the same (essentially, if they're in the same location in the memory)" is still wrong, `==` can compare by value as I just said. There's also no primitives in Python, everything (including ints) is an object.